# android settings: not found (/system/bin/settings missing)

Tags: android, root, airplane-mode

I've built a tasker like app called Condi.
In order to enable disable airplane mode in the latest Jellybeans and higher I use this terminal command:

```
settings put global airplane_mode_on 1
```

this works well but on some phones the settings command is missing. when it's present you can find it at /system/bin/settings (the problem is not the path, it's just missing entirely)

here's a copy of "settings" (the commands it performs):

```
# Script to start "settings" on the device
#
base=/system
export CLASSPATH=$base/framework/settings.jar
exec app_process $base/bin com.android.commands.settings.SettingsCmd "$@"
```

so what i tried is to run it directly by doing

```
export CLASSPATH=/system/framework/settings.jar
exec app_process /system/bin com.android.commands.settings.SettingsCmd put global airplane_mode_on 1
```

which worked on my phone (with settings present in the first place) but the two volunteer testers (without settings) both claim doing this in a terminal emulator app - crashes without doing it's thing.

does anyone know how it can / should be done properly ?

thanks!

Comment: What happens if you copy the settings executable into your assets folder and try to execute it from there?

Comment: for now i just asked the testers to copy it to the downloads folder and chmod 777 it but the permission didn't stick. i think sdcard is mounted with no-execute flag. what asset folder can i use for this that will give me exec permissions?

Comment: Sincerely, I don't know much about permissions. But you could do so: from the app's assets folder, copy (if not already existing) the file to your ... /bin(?) system executable folder. Then execute the settings program from there (as you would do normally). It should work (maybe, a chmod could be necessary).

Comment: A rooted device is needed to copy a file to /bin.

Comment: root is not an issue. you mean /system/bin right?
is there a folder i can test this in that doesn't need a remount?